# How to fund my option house account(trading account) from india using a local bank?

Tags: india, trading, stock-exchanges, international, funding

I would like to know how to fund my option house account(Trading account) from India ?

1. Option house is a US based brokerage firm
2. Why would an Indian citizen need to fill up form 15CA & 15CB to wire funds from Indian saving account to Trading account based in USA ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Option house is a US based brokerage firm

You can make a SWIFT payment giving the details of the Broker account, Bank, SWIFT BIC [or ABA]. The broker should be able to provide you the details.

> Why would an Indian citizen need to fill up form 15CA & 15CB to wire funds from Indian saving account to Trading account based in USA ?

As per FEMA [[Foreign Exchange Management Act]](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FEMA_FAQs.aspx), any transfer by individuals outside of India need the 15CA & 15CB form. The 15CA is from a CA to state that taxes have been paid on the funds being transferred. The limit is 1 million USD per year.

Comment: Thank you for the information , its been really help full mr.dheer!!!